# Is there a python version of MATLAB's place function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, eigenvalue

MATLAB's [place](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/place.html) function is pretty handy for determining a matrix that gives you the desired eigenvalues of a system.

I'm trying to implement it in Python, but [numpy.place](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-046cf7230c3f738a12bf552fc7f13c3ee1715813) doesn't seem to be an analagous function and I can't for the life of me seem to find anything better in the numpy or scipy documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Found this and other control functions in [Python Control Systems Library](http://python-control.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html)